# (0xC0000409) Stack overflow while calling C dll from Python working on one machine but not the other

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a Python script which calls a C dll to calculate some motor movement commands. It has been working for about 2 years while the C dll gets continuous updates. Recently the C dll which used to use GSL libraries for math (just parroting I don't know much about the dll itself) was updated to no longer use separate dlls. Now when I run it from terminal/console it crashes silently. Running from Pycharm I receive Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409).

Here is the troubleshooting plus facts thus far:

- Python script works correctly on DLL dev's PC
- Crash occurs on 3 other PCs that are not used by the DLL dev.
- One of the crashing PCs has an identical Python environment to the DLL dev's Python environment.
- Installing Visual C++ Redistributables (every major year version 64 and 32bit [DLL is 32bit]) has not helped.
- DLL works on production equipment which does not use Python (The Python script is part of our SW testing.)

Any thoughts on what to try/research next?

I can not share the DLL of course but I can share the function I use to call the DLL though keep in mind the code worked in the past and works on another PC. If it may be helpful to work around the problem with a code change then I will share.

Thanks

Comment: Different versions of the DLL?  Different OS versions or patch levels? Different stack size settings? You need to provide a lot more information, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Then the problem is (most likely) in the *Python* script. Please add it (and also the function signatures from *C*). [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Does the old *.dll* still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the new DLL had a hard coded file path for a log file it writes. Since the directory path did not exist the DLL would crash with the generic stack overflow message.

The solution I implemented was to ensure the directory exists and create it if necessary within the Python code before calling the DLL.